# Meaning of Proverbs 4:18

Tags: proverbs

In Proverbs 4:18 (NASB)

> But the path of the righteous is like the light of dawn
>
> That shines brighter and brighter until the full day.

What's the meaning of this metaphor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prov 4:18 should not be separated from the previous and subsequent verse which forms a literary contrast.  The thought begins in V14 as follows:

> 14 Do not set foot on the path of **the wicked** or walk in the way of
> evildoers.
>
> 15 Avoid it; do not travel on it. Turn from it and pass on by.
>
> 16 For they cannot sleep unless they do evil; they are deprived of
> slumber until they make someone fall.
>
> 17 For they eat the bread of wickedness and drink the wine of
> violence.
>
> 18 The path of the righteous is like the first gleam of dawn, shining
> brighter and brighter until midday.
>
> 19 But the way of **the wicked** is like the darkest gloom; they do not
> know what makes them stumble.

The metaphor is a common one throughout Scripture as often noted by many commentators where the righteous enjoy "light" (John 8:12, Ps 27:1, Mal 4:2, 2 Sam 23:4, etc) and the wicked are in "darkness" (1 John 1:7, John 12:35, Prov 11:10, Isa 8:22, etc)

The fact that God Himself is depicted as being in "light" emphasizes this point/metaphor:

> 1 John 1:5 - And this is the message we have heard from Him and
> announce to you: **God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all**.

The fact that the righteous follow the "Sun of righteousness" (Mal 4:2) and Jesus is called the "light of the world (John 8:12), AND that according to Prov 4:18 the righteous shine and this light is growing, means that the righteous grow in their knowledge and relationship with Jesus.

Ellicott succinctly observes:

> (18) But the path of the just . . .—The just have the Lord for their
> light (Psalm 27:1), on them the “Sun of righteousness” has arisen
> (Malachi 4:2). as “the light of the morning, even a morning without
> clouds” (2Samuel 23:4), and this light, that is, their knowledge of
> God, will become clearer and clearer till the “perfect day,” when they
> shall see Him as He is (1John 3:2). (Comp. Job 11:17; and Notes on
> Proverbs 6:23.)